# C compilation errors on using stdprn

Tags: c, windows, compilation, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

My OS is: Windows 8

IDE: VS 2012

Here is my C program. (from book)

```
/* print_it.c—This program prints a listing with line numbers! */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void do_heading(char *filename);

int line = 0, page = 0;

int main( int argv, char *argc[] )
{
  char buffer[256];
  FILE *fp;

  if( argv < 2 ) 
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "\nProper Usage is: " );
    fprintf(stderr, "\n\nprint_it filename.ext\n" );
    return(1);
  }

  if (( fp = fopen( argc[1], "r" )) == NULL )
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "Error opening file, %s!", argc[1]);
    return(1);
  }

  page = 0;
  line = 1;
  do_heading( argc[1]);

  while( fgets( buffer, 256, fp ) != NULL )
  {
    if( line % 55 == 0 ) 
      do_heading( argc[1] );
    fprintf( stdprn, "%4d:\t%s", line++, buffer );
  }

  fprintf( stdprn, "\f" );
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}

void do_heading( char *filename )
{
  page++;

  if ( page > 1)
    fprintf( stdprn, "\f" );

  fprintf( stdprn, "Page: %d, %s\n\n", page, filename );
}
```

Trying to compile. Opened Developer Command Prompt, and typed

```
cl print_it.c
```

Got this screen (bunch of errors and warnings)

http://content.screencast.com/users/TT13/folders/Jing/media/ff48bfe2-7e83-4d93-b1c5-db7ab7e553b8/2012-08-21_1458.png

What am I missing?

Comment: How old is that book? I haven't seen `stdprn` used in... ages!

Comment: -1 for posting a **screenshot** of text.

Comment: Also, what kind of quotes are you using? `“` seems like some kind of special UNICODE character, and not the standard ASCII `"` quote. Even if VC++2012 accept them don't bet on that other compilers will.

Comment: And a third point, if you are using VS2012, why are you compiling from the command line instead of from inside the IDE?

Comment: @KerrekSB which text? What are you talking about?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Fixed along with indentation :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Show me the place where I used, unicode doublequotes. They all are standtar double quotes "

Comment: @epic_syntax: Your screenshot of your terminal. Can't you copy the text from it? It'd allow for searchability, such that people who encounter similar problems in the future are more likely to find the solution by using text search (like google, stackoverflow-search, whatever). Regarding the quotes: I fixed that, see my edit, and you will notice that you *did* use unicode quotes.

Comment: So how to remake program to do same job with cross platform support? Can you help?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Book is 2012 edition. But for starters

Comment: Can anyone help me to modify code so that, it work on windows too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**stdprn** isn't part of standard C. stdprn is a stream DOS compilers provided. Should probably be avoided.

You could try *turning off* ANSI compatibility to get `stdprn` to work.
(**[Reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/23976)**)

Comment: Use the /Ze option as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa278577(v=vs.60).aspx).

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon The /Ze option is deprecated. Disable /Za option.

Comment: So how to remake program to do same job with cross platform support? Can you help?

Comment: @epic_syntax From a portability point of view it can't be done. You could however print to `stdout` and then redirect to a printer device, or pipe the output to a command that sends input to a printer. This _will_ be portable on all platforms, Windows _and_ Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 1):

you can type "stdout" instead of "stdprn"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Apologies if this has been incorrectly flagged. The comment has been removed the solution has been upvoted.