# Access Printer through C code

Tags: c, printing

This a sample code that will access a (peripheral drive) printer. But it seems `stdprn` is not working. How can i make it alive? Or is there other suitable method to print anything by printer.

```
/*print_it.c-This program preints a listing with line numbers */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void do_heading(char *filename);
int line = 0, page = 0;
int main( int argv, char *argc[] )
{
    char buffer[256];
    FILE *fp;
    if( argv < 2 )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nProper Usage is: ");
        fprintf(stderr, "\nprint_it filename.ext\n" );
        return(1);
    }
    if (( fp = fopen(argc[1], "r" )) == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Error opening file %s!", argc[1]);
        return(1);
    }
    page = 0;
    line = 1;
    do_heading( argc[1]);
    while( fgets( buffer, 256, fp ) != NULL )
    {
        if( line % 55 == 0 )
            do_heading(argc[1] );
        fprintf(stdprn, "%4:\t%s" , line++, buffer );
    }
    fprintf( stdprn, "\f" );
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
void do_heading( char *filename )
{
    page++;
    if ( page > 1 )fprintf(stdprn, "f" );
    fprintf( stdprn, "Page: %d, %s\n\n", page, filename );
}
return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C compilation errors on using stdprn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052484/c-compilation-errors-on-using-stdprn)

Comment: Sorry That was a typo. @ René Kolařík

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `stdprn` is something that existed in some MS-DOS compilers in the 1980's. It's not part of any C standard nor is it implemented in modern compilers.

You *may* be able to define it yourself by adding this to your program:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define PRINTER_DEVICE "PRN"
#else  /* assume unix */
#define PRINTER_DEVICE "/dev/lp0"
#endif

FILE *stdprn = fopen(PRINTER_DEVICE, "w");
/* should check for errors if stdprn == NULL */
```

Comment: If it is so backdated Then is there any suitable method to print anything by printer? @Joni

Comment: No portable ones, you'll have to use operating system APIs. If the printer is connected to the machine physically (not a network printer), opening the printer device and writing plain text to it "may" work but you won't be able to set fonts or print graphics.

Comment: "**If the printer is connected to the machine physically (not a network printer), opening the printer device and writing plain text to it "may" work**" just tell me how it can be done. I just need to print few lines.

Comment: That's right. I thought there might be other solutions. thanks for your reply. :) @Joni